# pytest: execute an action once in a module containing multiple tests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a pytest module that contains a class; this class subclass from Unit tests and I use pytest to run each user case in the class.

```
class myclass(unittest.TestCase)

    #vars and such

    def setup(self)
        #setup stuff for every test

    def tearDown(self)
        #teardown stuff for every test

    def test_test1(self)
        #code

    def test_test2(self)
        #code

    def test_test3(self)
        #code
```

when running I get the setup and teardown executed for every test; which is expected and it is what I want; but I may want to use a function or set some variables only once per test run (so once and not repeat for N test numbers). Is this possible?

Comment: are you referring to [`fixtures`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html)?

Comment: Not sure, never used fixtures. I will look into it. All that I want is to execute operations once when I run the module with all the tests in.